# Change value for nested dictionary key

Tags: swift, dictionary, nested

I've got following var of which I need to change/update for example the *'dateTime'* value of the key *'end'* with a value the user has put in.

```
 var calendarEvent = [
        "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
        "body": [

                "contentType": "HTML",
                "content": "Does late morning work for you?",

        ],
        "start": [

                "dateTime":"2017-12-10T12:55:00",
                "timeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time"

        ],
        "end": [

                "dateTime": "2017-12-10T14:00:00",
                "timeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time"

        ],
        "location": [

                "displayName": "Antwerpen"

        ],
        "attendees": [],
] as [String: AnyObject]
```

Let's say we do not care about the user input - as it is merely a String - and just want to replace the value with the word *'yea boi'*.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use a datatype that is designed for your program, instead of a dictionary.

Comment: I need to post a JSON to the api. The dictionary gets formatted to JSON in the needed class.

Comment: I just need to know how to update the value of a certain key in this dictionary.

Comment: Use a datatype that is designed for your program and can be serialized to JSON. If you're working with Swift 4 [this is nearly automatic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least error-prone, easiest, and most portable way is to define structs and use the `Codable` protocol along with `JsonEncoder` and `JsonDecoder` to read and write the JSON string for your endpoint. Then if you need to change a certain `key` you can simply treat it as any other struct and change it directly.

```
import Foundation

// structures for encoding/decoding

struct Body: Codable {
  let contentType: String
  let content: String
}

struct Time: Codable {
  let dateTime: String
  let timeZone: String
}

struct Location: Codable {
  let displayName: String
}

struct CalendarEvent: Codable {
  var subject: String // mutable
  let body: Body
  let start: Time
  let end: Time
  let location: Location
  let attendees: [String]
}

// set up structure

var event = CalendarEvent(subject: "Let's go for lunch",
                body: Body(contentType: "HTML",
                            content: "Does late morning work for you?"),
                start: Time(dateTime:"2017-12-10T12:55:00",
                             timeZone: "W. Europe Standard Time"),
                end: Time(dateTime:"2017-12-10T14:00:00",
                           timeZone: "W. Europe Standard Time"),
                location: Location(displayName: "Antwerpen"),
                attendees: [])

// change the subject
event.subject = "yea boi"

// create encoder

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
jsonEncoder.outputFormatting = [.prettyPrinted, .sortedKeys]

// encode, convert to a String, and print it

if let jsonData = try? jsonEncoder.encode(event),
  let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
  print(jsonString)
}

// output

/* {
     "attendees" : [],
     "body" : {
       "content" : "Does late morning work for you?",
       "contentType" : "HTML"
     },
     "end" : {
       "dateTime" : "2017-12-10T14:00:00",
       "timeZone" : "W. Europe Standard Time"
     },
     "location" : {
       "displayName" : "Antwerpen"
     },
     "start" : {
       "dateTime" : "2017-12-10T12:55:00",
       "timeZone" : "W. Europe Standard Time"
     },
     "subject" : "yea boi"
   }
*/
```

Note the mutated subject, changed from "Let's go for lunch" to "yea boi".

Comment: thank you very much for you fast and understandable response! I'm going to try this out as soon as I've got the time! Again, thank you very much!

Comment: The key is that as long as every member of a `struct` adheres to `Codable` or is a primitive (which by default adhere to `Codable`) then the entire `struct` can adhere to `Codable` without any additional code. Also, remember to accept the most correct answer (not just upvote it) so that other people can see the answer that worked for you.